# React useState is undefined after I gave it a value in another method

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this useState:

```
    const [round, setRound] = useState();
```

and I give it value here:

```
if (phase == 2) {
            const cookies = new Cookies();
            const url = "http://localhost:7101/GetAllPlayerRounds?userID=" + cookies.get('UserID');
            fetch(url)
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data[0]);
                    setRound(data[0]);
}
```

[image: the data in console.log is this]
Afterwards, if I want to use it, in for example phase 3 (so in another method), the useState return "undefined". This is the case for a few more useStates. It is like, I am giving it a value and then it doesn't even save it and is again null. I guess I am doing something wrong but I can't really find a solution to this, so would be glad if someone can point me in a direction.

Comment: You can add an initial value to `useState(myValue)`, if you don't set one it will default to `undefined`.

It could be that you're checking the `round` value before fetch has finished so it's logging `undefined`.

Try putting an initial value like: `useState('blaah')` then you'll know for sure if it logs the string.

Comment: @cd3k I just found that I didn't put [] inside the useState as it is an array, so it should be useState([]) but still doesn't fix my problem. It shouldn't be the case with the late fetch data, as I have made the same way another useState but instead of round its game and once I set the data for that useState game I can use it without a problem.

Comment: Just to clarify, after re-reading you problem. Calling `setRound` will update the `round` value, it won't effect the return value of `useState`. Just mentioning in case you where expecting `useState` to change it's return value.

The only two things I can think of are either, `data[0]` is undefined or you're checking `round` before it's been assigned. Try rendering `round` somewhere in the html so you can see the value as it gets updated by `setRound`. Eg: `<div>{ round }</div>`